# Haskell lists combine function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I want to write a recursive function that gets two lists + a requirement as input and outputs all possible tuples with one element each from the 1st and 2nd list that meet the requirement.

It should look something like this:

combine [1,2,3] [5,6,7] (\a b -> a+b > 7) -> [(1,7),(2,6),(2,7),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7)].

I currently just have:

```
combine:: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)] 
combine [] ys = []
combine xs [] = []
combine (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : combine xs ys
```

but it doesn't filter for anything.

Comment: Okay so write it. Where did you get to?

Comment: You need to compute the cross product of the two lists (use the `Applicative` instance), then filter the resulting pairs. A list comprehension is also a compact way to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

That makes sense, since your input does not filter for anything. You should add an extra parameter here:

```
combine:: [a] -> [b] -> (a -> b -> Bool) -> [(a, b)]
combine [] ys _ = []
combine xs [] _ = []
combine (x:xs) (y:ys) p
  | … = …
  | otherwise = …
```

here `p` is thus a function that takes an `a` and a `b` and returns a `Bool`, depending on the outcome you thus fire one of the two guards. I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.

If you want to produce all possible combinations for `x` and `y` for which the condition holds, list comprehension is a better tool. You can then work with:

```
combine:: [a] -> [b] -> (a -> b -> Bool) -> [(a, b)]
combine xs ys p = [ … | … <- xs, … <- ys, … ]
```

Comment: The OP's attempt zips the list, rather than computing the Cartesian product that the desired result indicates.